# jquery hover not working on my list items

Tags: jquery, html, html-lists, jquery-hover, mousehover

I am going thru a strange problem,I added hover function to my list items which are generated dynamically using ajax, but nothing is happening.The code is executing without any errors but with no effect.Even the alert is not displaying for mouseenter and mouseout.The alert pops up once in a while but not everytime.I am using the following code.

```
$('.category_list li').live("mouseenter", function() { 
alert('I m here');
  $(this).find('.category_list').css('text-decoration','underline');
}).live("mouseleave", function() {
alert('I m gone');
  $(this).find('.category_list').css('text-decoration','none');
});
```

My html code is

```
htmlData.push('<ul class="category_list">');
htmlData.push('<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="callGetApplicationDetails('+iIndex+',0);" >'+categoryName+'</a></li>');
```

Please help me since i am stuck very badly.

thanks
Hemish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the `mouseover` and `mouseout` events. I believe your filtering selector was looking for the `<li>` elements parent?

```
$('.category_list li').live('mouseover mouseout', function(event) {
    if (event.type == 'mouseover') {
        alert('I m here');
        $(this).parent().css('text-decoration','underline');
    } else {
        alert('I m gone');
        $(this).parent().css('text-decoration','none');
    }
});
```

---

and you could probably clean up the jQuery a little with a new css class

```
.category_list.over
{
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

and use `toggleClass()`

```
$('.category_list li').live('mouseover mouseout', function(event) {
    if (event.type == 'mouseover') { alert('I m here'); } 
    else { alert('I m gone'); }

    $(this).parent().toggleClass('over');
});
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.Now with this code, I am getting alert('I m gone') everytimes even when i am not on the categorylist li. Eventhough i am moving my mouse somewhere else, i m getting this alert. can you please help me with this. thanks

Comment: Keep in mind that `mouseover/mouseout` events bubble. OP was correct in using `mouseenter/mouseleave`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to support IE6 with this feature, use CSS instead:

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/QLsQp/

```
.category_list li a {
    text-decoration:none;
}

.category_list li:hover a {
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

This uses the `:hover` pseudo selector to affect the nested `a` element when a `li` is hovered.

---

The trouble with your javascript is that this:

```
$(this).find('.category_list')
```

...won't find anything, because `.category_list` is an *ancestor* of the `<li>` elements, not a *descendant*.

You would need this instead:

```
$(this).find('a')
```

Comment: HiPatrick.                                                           I used this code, but still not able to get any alerts. $('.category_list li ').live("mouseenter", function() { 
alert('I m here');
 $(this).find('a').css('text-decoration','underline');
}).live("mouseleave", function() {
alert('I m gone');
  $(this).find('a').css('text-decoration','none');
});            Will you please throw some light..

Comment: @user: Could you please post in your question the actual HTML markup. You should be able to copy & paste it using developer tools after it has rendered. Your code should work. [Here's an example using your code.](http://jsfiddle.net/kqY63/)

Comment: @Patrick. it works on html dev. tool but not on my mozilla and internet browsers.Where am i wrong?

Comment: @Can its container div blocks it or filter it something like that?

Comment: @user: Yes. Because you're using `.live()`, the event handler is actually placed on the `document`, and waits for the event to bubble up, and if the element that caused the event matches the `'.category_list li'` selector, it fires. So anything that *prevents* bubbling of the event will cause the event to never reach the `document`. The only way the bubbling would be prevented would be if you had a handler on the container (or some other ancestor of the `li` element) that does `return false;` or `event.stopPropagation()`. Those will kill the bubbling, and the event will never reach `.live()`.

Comment: ...in that case, a better solution may be to use `.delegate()` instead of `.live()`. Same concept, but the handler is placed on whatever ancestor you designate instead of all the way up on the `document`. I would update my answer, but it seems that your `.category_list` is being dynamically generated. You'd need to place the `.delegate()` handler on the closest ancestor that is present when the page loads. Let me know what that is, and I'll update my answer.

Comment: @patrick: For ur reference, I used this code also and was successful till certain extent. But everytime i am getting mouse out alert only not mouse enter when i am using on my browser but it runs correctly on dev tools. This is the code.

Comment: $('.category_list li').live('mouseenter mouseout', function(event) {
     if ((event.type == 'mouseenter') && ($(event.target).is('.category_list li'))) 
     { alert('I m here'); 
      if(event.preventDefault)
            {
            event.preventDefault()
            }
            else{
            event.returnValue=false;
      }
    } 
    else if((event.type == 'mouseout') && ($(event.target).is('.category_list li')))
    { 
     alert('I m gone'); 
          //Now event default code.Not writing this bcoz of space crunch. I am getting I am gone everytime not I am here.

Comment: @patrick: Here is the DOM hierarchy ...................<div id="left_cln_box"> 
<ul class="category_list">
<li><a>New&nbsp;To Android</a></li>
<li><a>Five&nbsp;App Friday</a></li>
</ul></div>..  Please let me know the possible changes. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Finally! I used livequery and it worked!

```
$('.category_list li').livequery("mouseenter", function() {
    $(this).css({'background-color' : '#A9A8A8'})
}).livequery("mouseleave", function() {
    $(this).css({'background-color' : '#F4F4F4'})
});
```

@Patrick:Thanks for the help.

Hope it will help others also.