# Setting hover on specific li menu items using JQuery

Tags: jquery, menuitem, jquery-hover

I have a menu and I would like to be able to be able to hover over the menu items under Policies and have a tool tip appear using JQuery. My thought would be to use the selector static.dynamic-children for Policies only.  From there set a hover action for the li tags that contain Policy 1, Policy 2 and Policy 3 and have the tool tip appear(The text can be anything for this example). This is where I'm stuck and don't know how to proceed.

What would be the best approach to do this? Any help would be much appreciated.

NOTE: The menu is dynamically generated by SharePoint hence all the attributes.

Here is the HTML for the menu:

```
<UL class="root static">
<LI class=static><A accessKey=1 class="static menu-item" href="/Pages/Welcome2.aspx">
            <SPAN class=additional-background>
                <SPAN class=menu-item-text>Home</SPAN>
            </SPAN></A>
            <UL class=static>
                <LI class="static dynamic-children" hoverDebouncer="0">
                    <SPAN class="static dynamic-children menu-item">
                        <SPAN class=additional-background>
                            <SPAN class=menu-item-text>Applications</SPAN>
                        </SPAN>
                    </SPAN>
                    <UL class=dynamic>
                        <LI class=dynamic><A class="dynamic menu-item new-window" href="http://localhost/App1/MyApp1.aspx" target=_blank><SPAN class=additional-background><SPAN class=menu-item-text>App 1</SPAN></SPAN></A></LI>
                        <LI class=dynamic><A class="dynamic menu-item" href="/Documents/MyApp2.aspx"><SPAN class=additional-background><SPAN class=menu-item-text>App 2</SPAN></SPAN></A></LI>
                        <LI class=dynamic><A class="dynamic menu-item new-window" href="http://localhost/App3/MyApp3.aspx" target=_blank><SPAN class=additional-background><SPAN class=menu-item-text>App 3</SPAN></SPAN></A></LI>
                    </UL>
                </LI>
                <LI class="static dynamic-children" hoverDebouncer="0">
                    <SPAN class="static dynamic-children menu-item">
                        <SPAN class=additional-background>
                            <SPAN class=menu-item-text>Policies</SPAN>
                        </SPAN>
                    </SPAN>
                    <UL class=dynamic>
                        <LI class=dynamic><A class="dynamic menu-item" href="/corp/Policy1/Shared%20Documents/Forms/Policies.aspx"><SPAN class=additional-background><SPAN class=menu-item-text>Policy 1</SPAN></SPAN></A></LI>
                        <LI class=dynamic><A class="dynamic menu-item" href="/corp/Policy2/Shared%20Documents/Forms/Policies.aspx"><SPAN class=additional-background><SPAN class=menu-item-text>Policy 2</SPAN></SPAN></A></LI>
                        <LI class=dynamic><A class="dynamic menu-item" href="/services/Policy3/Resources/Forms/Policies.aspx"><SPAN class=additional-background><SPAN class=menu-item-text>Policy 3</SPAN></SPAN></A></LI>                            
                    </UL>
                </LI>
                <LI class=static>
                    <A class="static menu-item" title="The Search Center displays search results" href="/SearchCenter/Pages/default.aspx"><SPAN class=additional-background><SPAN class=menu-item-text>Search</SPAN></SPAN></A>
                </LI>
            </UL>
        </LI>
    </UL>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you taken a look at [jquery hover not working on my list items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121028/jquery-hover-not-working-on-my-list-items?rq=1)?

You can add a class `hoverable` or similar to your Policies menu section. Then set up a selector `.hoverable li` and use the link above to fire your code to open a tooltip.

If you just want a plain tooltip, you can add `title='Tooltip here'` attribute to your `li`. e.g. `<li title="blah blah">My Menu Item 3</li>`.

You can also use jQuery UI for a nicer advanced tooltip: http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/

Update: selector `$(".dynamic-children:nth-child(2) li").attr("title", "hi");` should do the trick. Check out http://jsfiddle.net/Qfx7c/ done with your HTML

Comment: au58, thanks I'll take a look at that link. Unfortunately I cannot programmatically add a hoverable class to the menu section as it is dynamically generated by SharePoint(no access to source code). I was hoping to work with the HTML that I have now.

Comment: Drexter, I updated with a selector that works. Try out the jsfiddle link.

Comment: au58, I think this will work for me.  Thank you again for taking the time to help.  Much appreciated!